# What is the best way to find out the all possible outcome of the fork() function in C?

Tags: c, fork

I am asked (in an assignment) to print all the possible outcomes of three nested fork() function implementation in a certain C program. Is there an easy to judge all the possible outcomes?
I cake the process graph, but what how to understand the possible outputs using that?

Comment: Read the documentation for `fork` and write programs that would trigger those results.

Comment: A C function won't "implement" `fork`, because it's an OS feature - do you mean "call-sites" instead? And please clarify what you mean by "nested".

Comment: If your program simply forks three times, resulting in eight processes, and you simply want to consider the order in which those eight processes might do one simple atomic thing each, then the things can occur in any of 8! = 40,320 orders. If you want to consider further effects, such as how process execution might be interleaved by the operating system during continuing execution, then it is generally infeasible to evaluate all possibilities.